# Compliation error with VS2015 - 'F': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'F'

Tags: c++

We are migrating from VS2005 to VS2015 and the same code compiles fine in VS 2005, but throws an error in VS 2015
"'F': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'F'"

```
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
template <class DLLEXPORT F> class DLLEXPORT QWCalloutManager {
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Any help on this??

Comment: mmm... are you building a DLL or an application? Maybe I'm wrong, but if my memory serves, the two cases [need to be treated differently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx).

Comment: it is a static library am trying to build. but even for an application, I think we get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite as:

```
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
template <class F> class DLLEXPORT QWCalloutManager {
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

There is no way to say that `F` must be an exported class (unless you can write a static assert for it).  You will just have to check it in code review.

Comment: This complies, but later when this is used in another project, it gives linker error

Comment: That's a different question.  We'll need to see at least how the template is instantiated, and the definition of the class you use for F, (and the linker error message of course).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe VS 2005 didn't complain but `template <class __declspec (dllexport) F> class ...` isn't valid MSVC++ syntax.

Try removing `DLLEXPORT` from the template argument.

```
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec (dllexport)
template <class F> class DLLEXPORT QWCalloutManager {
};
```